# maximumPoolSize in Camel-Netty

Tags: apache-camel, netty, apache-karaf

I have been playing around with camel-netty and camel-netty-http components, and trying to figure out what the setting maximumPoolSize does.

However, from what i observe based on this is that, the OrderPool always processes 16 concurrent requests. I am trying to change the maximumPoolSize to a value of 5 like the route as below,

```
<bean id="nettyBean" class="com.redhat.NettyTestImpl">
        <property name="message" value="Netty maximumPoolSize test"/>
    </bean>

    <camelContext trace="false" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint" autoStartup="true">
        <route>
            <from uri="netty-http:http://localhost:8080/hello?maximumPoolSize=5&amp;sync=true"/>

            <log message="Forwarding to Netty component ....."/>
            <setBody>
                <method ref="nettyBean" method="sayHi"/>
            </setBody>
            <delay>
                <constant>3000</constant>
            </delay>

            <log message="The body contains : ${body}"/>
        </route>
    </camelContext>
```

But it seems that i cannot get the maximumPoolSize to set to a value. So, what am i doing wrong ? How can i get the maximumPoolSize set ?

I check this by load testing with 20 concurrent requests and all are processed.

Answer (score 0):

I just checked the code of camel-netty and camel-netty-http, maximumPoolSize is used for the OrderPool, you can use jconsoler to check the thread pool size.
As the OrderPool is used to handle the processor of camel, netty still has the work thread to handle the connection, which means it can still server 20 concurrent request, this time. But the TPS could be just about 5.